# "Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s)" error when building app

Tags: flutter, dart

Literally, I dunno what's this error but it's driving me so mad & insane 'cause I can't find a solution for it anywhere. This is the logs :-

```
Launching lib\main.dart on M2003J15SC in debug mode...
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
D/ViewRootImpl(13011): setSurfaceViewCreated, created:true
W/Gralloc3(13011): mapper 3.x is not supported
E/gralloc (13011): Arm Module v1.0
E/ion     (13011): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
I/OpenGLRenderer(13011): Davey! duration=3774ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=96490622784117, Vsync=96490672684317, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=96490681854520, AnimationStart=96490681917827, PerformTraversalsStart=96490681921827, DrawStart=96493192666135, SyncQueued=96493249170751, SyncStart=96493252131981, IssueDrawCommandsStart=96493261355981, SwapBuffers=96494372612058, FrameCompleted=96494400707366, DequeueBufferDuration=13546000, QueueBufferDuration=24723000,
E/libEGL  (13011): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
W/Looper  (13011): Slow Looper main: Long Msg: seq=18 plan=02:47:05.783  late=59ms wall=3740ms running=32ms runnable=13ms io=143ms reclaim=18ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver
I/Choreographer(13011): Skipped 236 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/System.out(13011): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System  (13011): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
W/Looper  (13011): Slow Looper main: doFrame is 3940ms late because of 9 msg, msg 1 took 3740ms (seq=18 running=32ms runnable=13ms io=143ms reclaim=18ms late=59ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver), msg 3 took 71ms (seq=20 running=1ms late=3789ms h=com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb w=7), msg 4 took 60ms (seq=21 running=6ms runnable=2ms io=52ms late=3859ms h=android.os.Handler c=com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppGateKeepersManager$2)
I/System.out(13011): [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out(13011): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out(13011): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/ActivityThread(13011): com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider acquiringCount 2
I/ActivityThread(13011): com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider acquiringCount 3
I/om.extreme.hel(13011): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 34088(1653KB) AllocSpace objects, 14(816KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 4494KB/6399KB, paused 11.665ms total 113.298ms
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:55458/g9NdSGKbod4=/ws
W/om.extreme.hel(13011): Long monitor contention with owner AsyncTask #2 (13110) at boolean android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int)(BinderProxy.java:-2) waiters=0 in android.content.IContentProvider android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, int, boolean) for 1.833s
W/om.extreme.hel(13011): Long monitor contention with owner AsyncTask #2 (13110) at boolean android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int)(BinderProxy.java:-2) waiters=1 in android.content.IContentProvider android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, int, boolean) for 1.625s
I/om.extreme.hel(13011): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=3403 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
I/System.out(13011): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System  (13011): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(13011): [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out(13011): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
D/Surface (13011): Surface::disconnect(this=0x7d5f4ed000,api=1)
D/Surface (13011): Surface::connect(this=0x7d5f4ed000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys(13011): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/Surface (13011): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x7d5f4ed000,bufferCount=3)
I/GED     (13011): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
D/Surface (13011): Surface::disconnect(this=0x7d5f4f2000,api=1)
D/Surface (13011): Surface::connect(this=0x7d5f4f2000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys(13011): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/Choreographer(13011): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer(13011): Davey! duration=870ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=96501483470494, Vsync=96501533370694, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=96501535010520, AnimationStart=96501535160982, PerformTraversalsStart=96501535163674, DrawStart=96502237188982, SyncQueued=96502244220597, SyncStart=96502245052674, IssueDrawCommandsStart=96502270612905, SwapBuffers=96502350599059, FrameCompleted=96502354922520, DequeueBufferDuration=74792000, QueueBufferDuration=2066000,
W/Looper  (13011): Slow Looper main: doFrame is 623ms late because of 1 msg, msg 1 took 737ms (seq=47 running=42ms runnable=9ms io=392ms late=51ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver)

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following ArgumentError was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(392.7, 834.9), devicePixelRatio: 2.8, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.dark, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 249.1), alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: false, highContrast: false, disableAnimations: false, invertColors: false, boldText: false, navigationMode: traditional)):[39;49m
Invalid argument(s)

[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSafeArea[39;49m
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#0      _StringBase.+  (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:267:57)[39;49m
[38;5;248m#1      new ApiService[39;49m
[38;5;248m#2      new _SplashScreenPageState[39;49m
[38;5;248m#3      SplashScreenPage.createState[39;49m
[38;5;244m#4      new StatefulElement[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(392.7, 834.9),
devicePixelRatio: 2.8, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.dark, padding:
EdgeInsets.zero, viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 249.1),
alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: false, highContrast: false, disableAnimations:
false, invertColors: false, boldText: false, navigationMode: traditional)):
Invalid argument(s)
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  [38;5;248mSafeArea[39;49m
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
[38;5;244m#0      _StringBase.+  (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:267:57)[39;49m
[38;5;248m#1      new ApiService[39;49m
[38;5;248m#2      new _SplashScreenPageState[39;49m
[38;5;248m#3      SplashScreenPage.createState[39;49m
[38;5;244m#4      new StatefulElement[39;49m
[38;5;244m#5      StatefulWidget.createElement[39;49m
...     Normal element mounting (147 frames)
[38;5;244m#152    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#153    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
...     Normal element mounting (273 frames)
[38;5;244m#426    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#427    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#428    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#429    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#430    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244m#431    BuildOwner.buildScope[39;49m
[38;5;244m#432    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree[39;49m
[38;5;244m#433    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#434    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s)

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
Invalid argument(s)
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSafeArea[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s)

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
Invalid argument(s)
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mSafeArea[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
```

It was normal yesterday but today when I tried to build the app it throws that error. I searched a lot but it was just a waste of time so I hope anyone here can fix it and end my madness :"((

Comment: I've opened an issue on Flutter main repo here :-
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who sees this, check your code again because the problem will be in it and **read the stacktrace correctly** and Insha'allah you'll be able to solve it as me. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a bit more details ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Okay, so when you look deeper in my logs for example u will see that there was an error related to `MediaQuery` and it's in the widget called `SafeArea`. So start from here. Go to your logs and search for a `Widget Name` or a `Property Name`

Answer (score -1):

I get same Error on webfeed package so you need to check versions on webfeed because it's not working properly. Try to upgrade your webfeed version and get dependencies again.